# tried running the contract but always getting the same error

Tags: solidity, erc-20, nodejs, hardhat

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9; 
import "opezeppilines/openzeppelin-contracts-master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract currency is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name,string memory symbol) ERC20(name,symbol)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender,10*10**18);
        
    }
}
```

**my currency.sol**

```
async function main()
{
    const {deployer} = await ethers.getSigners();
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("currency");
    const token = await Token.deploy();
}

main().then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch(
err => {console.error(err);
process.exit(1);
});
```

**My deploy.js**

```
PS E:\vs code files> npx hardhat run --network Goerli scripts/deploy.js
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
× Help us improve Hardhat with anonymous crash reports & basic usage data? (Y/n) · y
Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=2, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
    at Logger.makeError (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:261:28)
    at Logger.throwError (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:273:20)
    at Logger.checkArgumentCount (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:332:18)
    at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1237:16)
    at step (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
    at ContractFactory.deploy (E:\vs code files\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:1138:16) {
  reason: 'missing argument:  in Contract constructor',
  code: 'MISSING_ARGUMENT',
  count: 0,
  expectedCount: 2
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

Comment: do i need to share my hardhat.config,js

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor needs 2 values as input, which you didn't provide in your script. The `name` and the `symbol`. Change your code line to somthing like this:

```
const token = await Token.deploy("tokenName", "tokenSymbol");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a typo in the first contract code you shared. You wrote `opezeppilines`, but it should be `openzeppelin`

Corrected here:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9; 
import "openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract currency is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name,string memory symbol) ERC20(name,symbol)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender,10*10**18);
        
    }
}
```